# How to call the SharePoint rest API using Java web application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, java-api, java

I have developed one of the web based Java Application in which one of the page containing the form for uploading a files, as of now uploaded file stored on the Application server, but instead of this I want storing file in the SHAREPOINT ONLINE 2013

I am not an expert in the SharePoint, so please explain in the step by step manner with proper flow and code

For token generation I am doing whatever mention here(http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/) and I was getting the token successfully and now not having a clue for what is the next step for the development?

Answer (score 0):

[Connect to Sharepoint Online REST API using Java](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239128/connect-to-sharepoint-online-rest-api-using-java?rq=1)

Above Link have diffrent question but answer contain everything what you want, Kindly check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JShare from here : [JShare API](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/tutorial/index.html)
It supports Microsoft SharePoint server 2013 and SharePoint Online / Office 365