# How to update ModerationStatus (approval status) of a file in share point using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, postman, java

after check in a file using rest api , it having approval status as 'draft', do we have any rest api url (postman) to update approval status of a file in share point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP POST:

> `https://<org>.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list title')/items(<item id>)`

Payload:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.ClientsListItem" // your might be different
    },
    "OData__ModerationStatus": 0,
    "OData__ModerationComments": "Approved by <user name>"
}
```

To find out your list's type you can issue http get to `https://<org>.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName`. You should also provide `x-requestdigest` in http headers, since it's POST request.

or change moderation status with [pnpjs](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs) library:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Clients').items.getById(1).update({
            'OData__ModerationStatus' : 0, // 1 - rejected
            'OData__ModerationComments': `Approved by <user name>`
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Sergei =>
I am trying to update using Java (Rest API)

Comment: Then just ignore the part about pnpjs :). I've added just for future reference if somebody uses javascript.

Comment: Thanks Sergei it works . I have just added one more answer with screen sort and my findings. Hope it will help some one.

Answer (score 1):

As told by Sergei Sergeev. We can change approval status of a file using Rest.

1. post request header.

We need all these parameters in header. (if access token have **fullControl** as permission then we even don't need **x-requestdigest** in header)

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization: Bearer <Your access token> 
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
If-Match: *
```

[image]

2. post request body
[image]

As you can see i got response as 204 - that's success. so after post above post request check your share point site.

Comment: BTW if you use bearer tokens, then you don't need request digest at all.