# Fetch an image from a SitePage using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Under one of our company's subsites, we have /SitePages/{employee-name}.aspx which is a normal SharePoint page with the employee's information in text plus their picture.
I'm looking for a way to loop through all SitePages and retrieve ONLY the image and save it locally with PowerShell. I've tried a number of cmdlets from the PnP PowerShell such as Get-PnPWikiPageContent, to no avail. Is it even possible to obtain specific elements of an aspx SharePoint page such as images?
Here's an example of what I tried:

```
Get-PnPWikiPageContent -ServerRelativePageUrl "/SitePages/{employee-name}.aspx"
```

If anyone could tell me how to do it from even a single page (without looping through them all) I'd be more than happy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no PowerShell cmdlet to get images from site pages.

The images on site pages are stored in the picture libraries, *Site Assets* library, personal OneDrive folder or external website (*Stock*), depending on how they are inserted on the page. If the employee pictures are all uploaded from local drives, you should be able to find them in the folder `SiteAssets/SitePages/<pagename>` and download them easily.

Or you can use other methods like REST API to get contents from the site page (or the folder as mentioned).
Sample reference: [Download and upload file from share point using Java (Rest API call).](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250827/download-and-upload-file-from-share-point-using-java-rest-api-call)